How to Filter Nested Values in Elasticsearch Using Python
I am successfully integrating Elasticsearch into my Python application but facing challenges with nested file type filtering. Specifically, I need the search to return assets that match the query, even if the nested file types don't match the user's filter. For example, if a query matches an asset and its PDF file, but the user filters for DOCX files, the asset should still be returned but without the PDF file. Currently, my attempts to filter by file type without excluding the entire asset have not been successful. Each asset includes a title, description, and metadata, with files that contain their own title, content, and FileType.
1. Data Retrieval and Index Mapping
I retrieved values from the database and manually created index mappings as follows:
mappings = {
    "properties": {
        "Title": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "edge_ngram_analyzer",
        },
        "Description": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "edge_ngram_analyzer",
        },
        "AssetId": {"type": "keyword"},
        "Category": {"type": "keyword"},
        "CreatedDate": {"type": "date"},
        "Language": {"type": "keyword"},
        "Files": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "Title": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "edge_ngram_analyzer",
                },
                "Content": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "edge_ngram_analyzer",
                },
                "FileType": {"type": "keyword"},
            }
        }
    }
}

2. Search and Filtering Implementation
I successfully implemented search and filters for metadata such as "CreatedDate", "Language", and "Category". Here’s how I structured my search queries:
search_query = {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "multi_match": {
                                "query": query,
                                "fields": ["Title", "Description"],
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "nested": {
                                "path": "Files",
                                "query": {
                                    "multi_match": {
                                        "query": query,
                                        "fields": [
                                            "Files.Title",
                                            "Files.Content",
                                        ],
                                    }
                                },
                            },
                        },
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "filter": [
            {
                "term": {
                    "category": {
                        "value": "category to filter"
                    }
                }
            }
            # Additional filters here
        ]
    }
}

3. Issue with Nested File Type Filtering
I am trying to implement filtering based on file type within the nested "Files" section, but I haven't succeeded yet in achieving the desired behavior. Specifically, my goal is to ensure that an asset which matches the search query is displayed, even if it includes files that do not match the specified file type filter. For example, if the search query matches both an asset and a nested PowerPoint file within that asset, but the user is only interested in PDF files, I want the asset to still be shown but without displaying the PowerPoint file.
I attempted to add a nested query combined with a bool > must > query and filters sequence to achieve this, but it did not work as expected. The current configuration either excludes the asset entirely if the nested file does not meet the file type criteria, or it includes all nested files regardless of type.
I would greatly appreciate any guidance or examples on how to correctly filter based on file type within a nested structure in Elasticsearch.

Since my problem is within the nested so i tried to make the filters in the nested as follows
{
    "nested": {
        "path": "Files",
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "multi_match": {
                            "query": query,
                            "fields": [
                                "Files.Title",
                                "Files.Content"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "filter": [
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "Files.FileType": {
                                "value": "filetype extension"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}


Thanks in advance!
